# What would happen to training when validation_split is 0 while training a Keras model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm referring to the `validation_split` parameter from the `fit` method from [Keras](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit):

> validation_split: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data
>   to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction
>   of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss
>   and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. The
>   validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data
>   provided, before shuffling.

I noticed that the default value is 0 instead of conventional 0.2 or 0.33. I can't wrap my head around why they chose to use 0 as the default value since I thought no validation set would always cause training to overfit. Am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: You are not wrong in that assumption, but arguably the best way to find out what exactly happens in this case is to actually conduct an experiment yourself.

Comment: No validation set will not *cause* anything in itself (overfitting or else); it will only limit *us* from seeing what the actual performance of our model on unseen data is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A validation set is used to *detect* overfitting, not having a validation set just means that you cannot detect overfitting. It does not mean that the model will automatically overfit. Remember that validation data is not used at all to train the model, so the model cannot possibly behave differently if validation data is not being used.

That said, having a default of no validation set makes sense, because in the end is a *human* who detects overfitting by looking at the learning curves and the difference between training and validation loss. This process cannot (currently) be automated, so a human has to decide a value for the validation split, or just provide validation data by itself in the `validation_data` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to define the validation data yourself, and you pass the argument `validation_data= (x_val, y_val)`

Sometimes you want a K-fold cross validation.

Sometimes you simply don't want validation data.

The system cannot assume your training data includes validation, that is not a good thing for the user.

As for overfitting, it depends on the model and the data. It's not necessarily true that it will always overfit.